# Change datasource for an existing pivot cache

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have about ten PivotTables, each one on another worksheet.

I need to change the data source for each one of them into the same value. `Pivotcaches.count` give me 1 for thisworkbook so I assume every Table points to this cache.

Have you some suggestions on how to change this cache and not create ten new ones?

Here is what I got :

```
Sub Test(Ziel As String, Zieltab As String)
    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim letzteZeile As Double
    Dim letzteSpalte As Double
    Dim Spalte As String
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim pC As PivotCache
    Dim pT As PivotTable


    letzteZeile = Workbooks(Ziel).Worksheets(Zieltab).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    letzteSpalte = Workbooks(Ziel).Worksheets(Zieltab).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Spalte = Split(Workbooks(Ziel).Worksheets(Zieltab).Cells(1, letzteSpalte).Address, "$")(1)

    Set RNG = Worksheets(Zieltab).Range("A1:" & Spalte & letzteZeile)



    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set pC = Wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="'" & Wb.Sheets(Zieltab).Name & "'!" & RNG.Address, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)


    For Each Ws In Wb.Sheets
        For Each pT In Ws.PivotTables
            Set pT.PivotCache = pC
        Next pT
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

This is the actual look of it. It says the Method would not Match or sth like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have only one Pivot Cache, you need to create a new one and then apply it to your Pivot Tables.

Here the Pivot Cache is created from the Range named `Named_Range` in the Sheet named `Sheet_Name`, I leave it to you to rename these to fit your need! ;)

```
Sub Test_Gring()
Dim wB As Workbook, _
    wS As Worksheet, _
    pC As PivotCache, _
    pT As PivotTable, _
    bCreated As Boolean

For Each wS In wB.Sheets
    For Each pT In wS.PivotTables
        If Not bCreated Then
            pT.ChangePivotCache wB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                      SourceData:="'Sheet Name'!" & Range("Named_Range").Address, _
                                      Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)   'xlPivotTableVersion12
            Set pC = pT.PivotCache
            bCreated = True
        Else
            If pT.CacheIndex <> pC.Index Then pT.CacheIndex = pC.Index
        End If
    Next pT
Next wS

'Save to delete unused Pivot Caches
wB.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thank for the cool answer. Doesn't Datasource need to be a string?

Comment: @Gring : Try the edit (I put 2 possibilities, I'll let you choose the one you prefer) ;)

Comment: Thank you , it normaly should work now :) , unfortunately my Program won't , I still get the Error 1004 on the Index Method and 483 on ChangePivotCache (Object doesn't Support this property or Method")

Comment: pC.Index returns 0 , is this normal ?

Comment: Pivot Caches . Count says, that I only have one Cache

Comment: I guess that you can only create a Pivot Cache if it used, so I change the code to apply it directly to the first Pivot Table and then set other Pivot Table to use that newly created Pivot Cache! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked finally after several hours :D

Comment: @Gring : Glad I could help! ;) Enjoy SO!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with R3UK's answer, but I've experienced too much cross-version trouble (Excel 2013 to Excel 2010) using the **Create** method for both PivotTables and PivotCaches. Either the last argument, *Version*, changed its name or the Excel 2013 (Application.Version 15.0) PivotTable standard (*xlPivotTableVersion15*) when used is not recognized by Excel 2010 (Application.Version 14.0) (standard *xlPivotTableVersion14*), I suppose.

I find the **Add** method less risky. It can be used to create PivotTables easily in a similar manner.

```
Sub ChangeCacheWithAdd()
Dim wB As Workbook, _
    wS As Worksheet, _
    pC As PivotCache, _
    pT As PivotTable, _
    bCreated As Boolean

For Each wS In wB.Sheets
    For Each pT In wS.PivotTables
        If Not bCreated Then
            Set pC = wB.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                   SourceData:="'Sheet Name'!" & Range("Named_Range").Address
            pT.ChangePivotCache pC
            bCreated = True
        Else
            If pT.CacheIndex <> pC.Index Then pT.CacheIndex = pC.Index
        End If
    Next pT
Next wS

'Save to delete unused Pivot Caches
wB.Save
End Sub
```